# Proper action and compactness

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

> **Proposition:** Suppose a group $\Gamma$ acts properly by isometries on a metric space $X$. If the action is cocompact then every element of $\Gamma$ is a semisimple isometry of $X$.

(Please refer to Bridson and Haefliger's book, page 229. Here is a     [link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3DjaqB08AwAC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=semisimple+isometry&source=bl&ots=eOT5YTX42o&sig=0JIhfdo1hL8R7bMfu8lkfr1EhDc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HmOJVI2EIMfyUJKthKgN&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=semisimple%20isometry&f=false).)

So I did this proof as follows and I never used the action is proper (ie. properly discontinuous). Can anyone suggest if there is a mistake? I use the notation from this book.

As the action is cocompact, $X=\cup \gamma_i K$ where $\gamma_i\in \Gamma$ and $K$ is a compact set in $X$. There is a sequence of points say $x_n$ such that 
$d_\gamma(x_n)$ converges to $|\gamma|$. So for each $x_n$ there is $\gamma_n$ such that $y_n=\gamma_n.x_n\in K$. As $K$ is compact there is a subsequence converging to say $y$. This $y$ gives us the minimal element we are looking for.

Comment: What does it mean to say that an entire group action is a semisimple isometry?

Comment: What does $|\gamma|$ represent, $\gamma \in \Gamma$?

Comment: What does $d_\gamma(x)$ represent? Sorry for all these questions, but your terminology and notation are not standard and need to be explained.

Comment: Sure I understand your concern. I gave a link to the book.

Comment: Regarding a semisimple isometry, your use of the terminology does not match the link you provide. That link explains *only* how a single isometry can be semisimple. It does not contain anything about how an entire group action can be a semisimple isometry. So your question seems to need some work before it makes sense.

Comment: After the definition 6.1 there is a 2 line paragraph that states "An action of a group by isometries of X is called semi-simple if all of its element are semi-simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you justify that $y$ minimizes the displacement function $d_{\gamma}$? You know that $$d(\gamma \cdot y , y)= \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} d(\gamma \gamma_n \cdot x_n, \gamma_n \cdot x_n)= \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} d( \gamma_n^{-1} \gamma \gamma_n \cdot x_n,x_n), $$

but $\gamma_n^{-1} \gamma \gamma_n$ depends on $n$, and properness is precisely used in order to replace $\gamma_n^{-1} \gamma \gamma_n$ with some $\overline{\gamma}$ independent on $n$.

In fact, it is possible for a group $\Gamma$ to act cocompactly on a metric space $X$ with a parabolic isometry. Let $X= \mathbb{H}^2= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \mathrm{Im}(z)>0 \}$ be the hyperbolic plane and let us define the following two isometries:

$$h : z \mapsto \lambda \cdot z \ \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ \ t : z \mapsto z+1,$$

where $\lambda >1$. It is not difficult to notice that $\Gamma= \langle h,t \rangle$ acts cocompactly on $X$ and that $t$ is a parabolic isometry. Of course, the action $\Gamma \curvearrowright X$ is not proper: for large enough $n$, $$d(h^{-n} t h^n(x),x)<1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer I want to ask one more thing in the same proposition 6.10 part (3) to arise at a contradiction to the criteria properness he used the ball B(x,r) and B(x,r+a+1) but these ball might not be compact as the space is just a metric space not proper ? Can you please explain this ?

Comment: If X is length space I show it is locally compact and complete by Hoff Rinow it is a proper geodesic space. But the proposition gives only metric space.

Comment: The authors use a different definition of properness, see I.8.3(1).

Comment: Right, but my point is to say that B(x,r+a+1) is compact.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your problem: compactness of the balls is not needed, they just apply their definition of properness.