# Proper action in "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature"

Tags: geometric-group-theory

(This question is related to [Proper action and compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063231/proper-action-and-compactness/1066725#))

In (I.8.2) of "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature", properly action is defined as: for each $x$, there exists a $r$ such that $\{\gamma | \gamma B(x,r) \cap B(x,r)\}$ is finite. (I think this does not implies that
$\{\gamma | \gamma B(x,r) \cap B(x,r)\}$ is finite **for any** $r$).

Then I find a problem about the proper action on [Page 233](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjDBI.jpg), which is highlighted:

From the proof of proposition 6.10 (3) on page 233,
we know that for all $n$ sufficently large  $\gamma_n B(x, r+a+1) \cap B(x, r)\ne \emptyset$. Then the original proof say this contradicts to the properness of the action (see I.8.3 (1)).
But the definition of proper action is I.8.2 as above, and I.8.3(1) just explain the proper action in (I.8.2) is more restrictive than the another proper action, which is defined as: for every compact subset $K$, the set $\{\gamma | \gamma . K \cap K\}$ is finite.
Why I.8.3(1) implies a contradiction?

(In fact in [Proper action and compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063231/proper-action-and-compactness/1066725#)
, after the answer by Seirios, there are comments by GGT, which ask the same question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they simply forgot to assume properness of $X$ or they forgot their definition of a proper action. Or they wrote the proof using one definition of a proper action, later change their definition but forgot to correct the proposition. The right thing to do is to write to Martin Bridson and ask him to add an erratum for this proposition.

Here is a counterexample to their claim of discreteness of the set of translation lengths (proposition 6.10(3)). Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $({\mathbf e}_n), n\in {\mathbb N}$. Take the sequence $a_n=1-\frac{1}{2n}$ and consider the translations
$$
T_n: {\mathbf x}\mapsto  {\mathbf x} + a_n {\mathbf e}_n, {\mathbf x}\in H. 
$$
Let $G$ denote the (free abelian) subgroup of isometries of $H$ generated by the translations $T_n$, $n\in {\mathbb N}$. Then the group $G$ acts properly on $H$ (in the sense of Bridson-Haefliger which, incidentally, is equivalent to the standard notion of properness for isometric actions of discrete groups): For each point ${\mathbf x}\in H$
the set
$$
\{g\in G| g B({\mathbf x}, \frac{1}{3}) \cap B({\mathbf x}, \frac{1}{3})\ne \emptyset\}
$$
is finite.

Let $X\subset H$ denote the $G$-orbit of zero, equipped with the restriction of the standard distance function on $H$. Then $G$ acts on $X$ properly, cocompactly (since the action is transitive). But the set of translation lengths of the elements of $G$ is not a discrete subset of ${\mathbb R}$ since it contains the sequence $(a_n)$.

Here is another counterexample, of combinatorial origin: Take the countably infinite bouquet of circles $Z$; assign length $a_n= 1- \frac{1}{2n}$ to the $n$th circle. This yields a $G$-invariant path-metric on the universal covering space $X$ of $Z$, where $G$ is the group of covering transformations. The group $G$ acts discretely and transitively on the vertex set of $X$. However, the set of translation lengths includes the sequence $(a_n)$, hence, is nondiscrete.

Comment: I hope there is other explanation  about this， although I totally have the same opinion as you about this. This book is studied by many people and proper action is discussed many times, but  I can not find any correction about this.

Comment: @user374918: It is a long book and, hence, is bound to have small mistakes like this. In the end, the authors are primarily interested in proper metric spaces, so the issue is mute. As for hoping: One can hope for many things, but mathematics is not about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comment. I have struggled this for a long time.  I am familiar only with abstract group. So  I have to stay prudent.  (in fact, I need more time to understand your counterexample.)

Comment: You write that "the authors are primarily interested in proper metric spaces", but they were very careful to provide proofs in the general (not necessarily proper) case wherever possible. So unless you have an actual counterexample, I wouldn't jump to this conclusion.

But it is also true that several of the exercises to have missing hypotheses. So this may indeed be the correct explanation!

Comment: @HJRW: If you read my answer you find that I gave an actual counterexample. Yes, the authors in general are careful making or not making properness assumption but the main application of I.8.2 is to hyperbolic and CAT(0) groups, in which case properness holds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan -- oh, it is an actual counterexample!  Your language ("Here is an example to think about") didn't make this clear.  I suggest you rewrite your answer slightly to make it clear from the outset that you are presenting a definitive answer to the question.

Comment: @HJRW: Done....

Comment: @HJRW I think you are the best person to tell Martin about this minor issue and ask him to add it to his list of errata

Comment: He has quite a long list... this may well already be on it!  But I'll let him know.

Comment: Where can I find the list of errata?

Comment: @Noobmathematician This question should be addressed to Dr. Bridson, not me. His email is easy to find.

Comment: Do I have to assume properness of X to argue in 6.10.(1) that infinitely many of those isometries will be equal to the same isometry $\bar\gamma$?

Comment: @Noobmathematician: If you have a question, do not ask it in comments, post a new MO question instead.