# Every proper and cobounded action is acylindrical.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

I am trying to show every proper and cobounded action is acylindrical. Given any $\epsilon> 0$, we need to show there exist $R, N > 0$, s.t. for every two points $x, y$ with $ d(x, y)\ge R$, there are at most $N$ elements
$g\in G$ satisfying $d(x, g x)\le\epsilon$ and $d(y, g y) \le\epsilon$. Since the action is proper, each orbit $G\cdot x$ is discrete, then in the compact set $\bar{B_\epsilon}(x)$, the intersection $G\cdot x\cap\bar{B_\epsilon}(x)$ is finite. Also, by the proper action, the stabilizers are also finite. So for given 2 points $x,y$, the number of elements $g\in G$ satisfying $d(x, g x)\le\epsilon$ and $d(y, g y) \le\epsilon$, say $N_{x,y}$, is finite. But how do we get a universal $N$ to bound all the $N_{x,y}$ when $x,y$ are apart enough? In particular, I am not sure how to apply the cobounded condition.

An action of a group $G$ on a metric space $S$ is called acylindrical if for every $\epsilon> 0$ there exist $R, N > 0$ such that for every two points $x, y$ with $ d(x, y)\ge R$, there are at most $N$ elements
$g\in G$ satisfying $d(x, g x)\le\epsilon$ and $d(y, g y) \le\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The proof below assumes that the space $X$ is proper, i.e., that closed balls are compact.  I think the statement is false without this statement.  See the comments below.

Since the action is assumed to be proper, this is in a sense a stronger condition than an acylindrical action.  So, it makes sense to try to focus on a single point $x$ and then to relate a second point $y$ by choosing a point in its orbit that is sufficiently close to $x$.  Since the action is cobounded, there will be a point that is, say, $R$-close to $x$, where $R$ does not depend on $x$ or $y$.  The $N$ will come from the finite number of group elements that fail to move an $R$-ball centered at $x$ off of itself.  Really, as we'll see, we'll use a $2R + 2\epsilon$ ball centered at $x$.

Let $G_{x,\epsilon} = \{g \in G \mid \overline{g.B(x,\epsilon)} \cap \overline{B(x,\epsilon)} \neq \emptyset\}$.  Let $N_{x, \epsilon}$ be the cardinality of $G_{x,\epsilon}$, which is finite for each $\epsilon \geq 0$ because the action is proper.

Here's an outline of what to show:

1. There is an $R > 0$ such that for any $x,y \in X$, the distance between their orbits is at most $R$.  This is the definition of cobounded.
2. Suppose $y \in X$ and $\epsilon \geq 0$.  Prove that $hG_{y,\epsilon}h^{-1} = G_{h.y,\epsilon}$.  It's the same proof as for showing the analogous statement for point stabilizers.
3. Fix a point $x \in X$ and let $y$ be any point in $X$.  Let $\epsilon \geq 0$. Prove that $N_{y,\epsilon} \leq N_{x,2R + 2\epsilon}$.  This latter number is the $N$ you seek.  The main idea is that if $g \in G_{y,\epsilon}$ and $h.y$ is $R$-close to $x$, then $hgh^{-1}.(h.y)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $h.y$ and so $hgh^{-1}.x$ is $2R + 2\epsilon$-close to $x$; therefore $hgh^{-1} \in G_{x,2R + 2\epsilon}$.  Conjugation by $h$ defines a bijection $G \to G$ and so there are at most $N_{x,2R + 2\epsilon}$ such elements $g \in G$.

Comment: Sorry, why can we have $h\cdot y$, s.t.  "$h\cdot y$ is $R$-close to $x$"? I think we only can find an $h\cdot y$ which is $R$-close to $G\cdot x$.

Comment: But I understand by No.2 in the outline, it indeed deduces to the case when $d(x,y)<R$.

Comment: Actually, I am a little confused because $\overline{B(x,\epsilon))}$ might not be always compact, for example, the Cayley graph of an infinite group $G$ with generating set $G\setminus\{1\}$. If it's not compact then $N_{x,\epsilon}$ might not always be finite.

Comment: You can find an $h \in G$ such that $h.y$ is $R$-close to $x$ because the action is cobounded.  I think that cobounded means that there is a point $z \in X$ and a $R > 0$ such that the $R$-balls centered at the points of the orbit of $z$ cover $X$.  If $y \in g_1.B(z,R)$ and $x \in g_2.B(z,R)$, then $h = g_2g_1^{-1}$ has the desired property.

Comment: I think you need to assume that the metric space is proper, so that closed balls are compact.  I think a counterexample can be constructed from the example in answer to the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3921685/4009